# How to create Hash with string keys by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, syntax, symbols

When I do the following:

```
h = { "a": 123 }
```

Ruby converts the key to a symbol automatically.

```
h[:a]  # => 123
h["a"] # => nil
```

How can I prevent this behaviour? I created the hash with a string key, and would like to keep it that way without always having to call `Hash#stringify_keys`.

Comment: `key: value` is just a shortcut for `:key => value`, so there is actually no string key in your example – `"a": 123` becomes `:"a" => 123` (note the leading `:`)

Comment: Could be nice maybe if { "a": 123 } uses an HashWithIndifferentAccess under the hood, as opposed to a Hash then.

Comment: @Joerg: you're welcome to submit a feature request :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev please quit giving advices like that. `HashWithIndifferentAccess` has nothing to do with ruby :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: You know I know :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I know you know but not all the readers might have the respective sense of humor. So, I consider it would be better to back-port `HashWithIndifferentAccess` into ruby in the first place.

Comment: @mudasobwa: and _then_ this feature request!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev indeed.

Comment: "Ruby/Rails converts the key to a symbol automatically." – No, it doesn't. You are using the literal notation for `Hash`es with `Symbol` keys. There is no conversion going on, because there was never a `String` to begin with. That's like saying `1234` converts the `String` to an `Integer` automatically. There was never a `String`, that's just the literal notation for an `Integer`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use hash rocket syntax:

```
h = { "a" => 123 }
#=> {"a"=>123}
h['a']
#=> 123
```

Comment: @Joerg it is how it was before new hash notation appeared.

Comment: Yeah I know ... but since the new notation - there's no going back :)

Comment: @Joerg what if you wanted to have some object as a key? `{ Object.new => :hello }` - there is no way to write it in the new form, so. New syntax works only for symbol keys, everything else needs to go old way.

Comment: True ... Still, when using a colon I guess it's confusing/frustrating when the string key gets modified to a symbol - been catching me out a lot. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Hashrocket isn't going anywhere. Also, it's looks pretty cool :)

Comment: @Joerg: wanna see ugly syntax? Here's one: `{:"user.name" => "Bill"}` I snapped my teeth every time I saw one of those. :) But then it became possible to write `{"user.name": "Bill"}`. Doesn't look as bad now, does it? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that should be `{ user: { name: 'Bill' } }` ;-)

Comment: @Stefan: that's not activerecord :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev BTW, using a proper font with ligatures (like [Hasklig](https://github.com/i-tu/Hasklig/)) makes hashrockets look _really cool_.

Comment: @mudasobwa: oohhh, nice!

Comment: @mudasobwa: gonna give it a try :)

Comment: @mudasobwa monospaced ligatures, that's genius!

Comment: @mudasobwa although I see an ugly [issue with `!=`](https://github.com/i-tu/Hasklig/issues/78)

Answer (score 15):

Use hashrocket `=>` instead of colon `:`

```
h = { "a" => 123 }
#=> {"a"=>123}
```

You can access the value now using

```
h["a"]
#=> 123
```

On a side note, if you're using rails and want to ensure the values are accessed with both symbol and string keys

You can make use of [`Hash#with_indifferent_access`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/with_indifferent_access)

```
h = { a: 123 }.with_indifferent_access
#=> {"a"=>123}

h[:a]
#=> 123
h["a"]
#=> 123
h['a']
#=> 123
```

Comment: This is the actual answer. It's pragmatic and useful. The others are interesting to dive into the underpinnings of how Ruby works and read the discussions but this gets you going immediately, with a suggestion for those using Rails as well. Nice job.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
h = { "a" => 123 }
```

Colon make your key a symbol.

Comment: Pity ... such an ugly notation ... :(

Answer (score 5):

To clear a misunderstanding:

> it's confusing/frustrating when the string key gets modified to a symbol

It wasn't a string to begin with. This is just another syntax for creating symbol keys. Consider:

```
:'foo-bar'.class # => Symbol
```

The idea is that sometimes, there can be characters in the symbol that look like something completely different.

For example, the above without quotes would mean *"create the literal symbol `:foo` and from it, subtract the value of the local variable/method invocation result `bar`"*. Previously, there was no way to construct such symbols, other than to use `String#to_sym`. And you have to agree this looks terrible:

```
{'foo-bar'.to_sym => 42, :this_now_needs_rocket_notation => 'baz'}
```

---

Quotes in general don't mean *string creation*, they mean *take as is* and/or define boundaries for something. Therefore, they incidentally make a lot of sense for literal string syntax, but this is not their only application.